# Java Memory Management in web application

Tags: java, memory-management, out-of-memory

we have an web apoplication which is executing the Query from JSP and storing the results set into Collection in the form of, `ArrayList<TreeMap<ColumnName, Value(String)>>`. It doesn't have pagination in the application. When the user search for the more number of records it is taking more time to load the page. if multiple user do the same kind of searches we get out of memory error. When we checked the time to retrieve the data, forming the collection object using result set taking lesser time which is around 10 sec for 50k records. but for rendering data into page it is taking more time around 5 mins. sometimes goes into not responding stage.

Here My question is, When the collection object which is used to store the result set data will be freed up to do the garbage collection. is it after the page completes the page rendering of data? if not, then when will get freed up?

Comment: You shouldn't ask yourself it it is garbage collected or not, but instead if it is *eligible* for garbage collection (since you generally can't control when GC runs and for how much). That said, I'd suggest you to avoid loading in memory so much information, since even if it will be freed in time, it's a lot of object creation and destruction, especially if you do not present all the data you retrieved. Either add pagination, of hardcode an upperlimit, nobody is going to read ten thousands of results.

Comment: I second watery and like to add that constructions like `ArrayList<TreeMap<ColumnName, Value(String)>>` indicate some serious design issue.

Answer (score 0):

*My question is, When the collection object which is used to store the result set data will be freed up to do the garbage collection. is it after the page completes the page reading of data? if not, then when will get freed up?*

As soon as the response gets committed,the date structure begins eligible for GC.As part of response getting committed from your servlet,the JSP iterates the collections and renders it into HTML response.When the response committing gets completed(HTML is rendered from the appropriate JSP),it becomes available for Garbage Collection.**When it will get freed up,only GC knows but it becomes eligible after HTML is rendered from your JSP(as part of committing of response**

I am assuming that your ResultSet coming from execution of SQL query is not being referenced from anywhere else.If it does,you would explicitly have to set it to null to tell the JVM that it is eligible for Garbage Collection

Comment: That's not necessarily true in all situations. If the collection is referenced somewhere out of the JSP, or passed to any other method that could reference the collection instance, it can't be destroyed.

Comment: Why not? If the static variable is set to `null`, then the instance can be collected.

Comment: @watery I assumed that the collection coming from SQL query is not used anywhere else.If it is used anywhere else,only GC can tell.Check my edit now